# Bad Access in Background thread drawing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, cgimage

## What I'm trying to Accomplish

1. Draw an image in a background thread
2. Convert the `CGImage` to a `UIImage` and add it to a `UIImageView` on the main thread.
3. Fade in the imageview, which is on a subclassed `UICollectionViewCell` from alpha value 0 to 1.
4. Do it all so theres no choppiness when scrolling the `UICollectionView`

## The Problem

The behavior, at first, acts normally, but quickly digressed into unpredictableness, and usually and quickly resulted in `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors, happening somewhere in the process of converting uiimage to cgimage or vice versa.

## The Code

```
    //setup for background drawing
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context;
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, 250, backgroundHeight - 112, 8, 250 * 4, colorSpaceRef, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);

    //Take the image I want drawn, convert to cgimage for background drawing
    CGImageRef  image = contentImage.CGImage;
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, backgroundHeight - 112), image);
    CGImageRelease(image);
    CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    imageRef = outputImage;

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addImageToView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGImageRelease(outputImage);
```

The addImageToView Method simply create an image and adds to my UIImageView

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
[photoView setImage:image];
```

These methods get called during the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, along with my method fadeInImage

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    photoView.alpha = 1;
}completion:nil];
```

When I run, I get the Bad Access calls and crashing.  I'm guessing it has something to do with the main thread and the background threads passing the images between one another. Any ideas? Thanks guys.

Comment: why are you doing this in cell for row at index path ? what are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, as long as you didnt create an image with `CGImageCreate` or used `CGImageRetain`, you dont have to use `CGImageRelease(image);`. It should release automatically once you stop using it. Check it out.

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html)

Comment: Wow, this appears to have solved my question, though it appears I'm still getting some choppiness.

Comment: create a custom uitableviewcell and let that handle the drawing of the image rather than the cellforrowatindexpath. Just a thought to help the choppiness

Comment: For choppiness, is it possible to do this image processing somewhere else other than cellForRowAtIndexPath. In this method, just add the image to ImageView. It is difficult to comment on that since I am not sure about the whole scenario here.

Comment: the drawing of the image is done in a custom uiCollectionViewCell, the cellForRowAtIndexPath simply determines WHICH image will be drawn.

Comment: So do you mean to say that each and every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is called, you will be creating an image using the above method?

Comment: I do save the CGImageRef as an instance variable and reuse it if I can. Is there a better way?

Comment: How about converting it to UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; and save image as instance variable and use. Does that make any difference? It would be better if we reuse it unless it is necessary to redraw again. Make sure the above method is executed the lesser number of times possible by saving UIImage objects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't release first image `CGImageRelease(image);`

And probably it is better to change:

```
CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
imageRef = outputImage;

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addImageToView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

To:

```
CGImageRef outputImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
UIImage* result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addImageToView:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And then:

```
- (void) addImageToView:(UIImage*) image {
    [photoView setImage:image];
}
```

Or even:

```
[photoView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Comment: Touching UIView/UIViewController from a background thread is a no-no according to the GameKit examples and may lead to rare crashes. Specifically, you're in a world of potential trouble if `-release` is called on a background thread.

Comment: I am sorry, where do you see the problem??

Comment: Using `photoView` from a background thread is specifically suspect (especially if you're using ARC); `self` is likely to be suspect too.

Comment: Got it, thanks. So in this case `[self.photoView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:YES];` with `atomic` property for `photoView` would be looking better, but of couse no guarantees for `self`.

Comment: Or even better to do this: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {[photoView setImage:result];}

Comment: Nope! In the first case, `self.photoView` *necessarily* causes a retain/(auto)release on the background thread if the property is atomic. In the second case, the block implicitly does a retain of `self` (assuming `photoView` is an ivar) which can break if `self` is a UIViewController.

Comment: why do `self.photoView necessarily causes a retain/(auto)release on the background thread`? it is just a getter, we touch only its `image` property.

Comment: Because an atomic accessor must ensure that `photoView` is not dealloced if another thread does `foo.photoView = nil`; this means the background thread *must* do a retain (and to "balance" the retain, an (auto)release). [Cocoa With Love](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/memory-and-thread-safe-custom-property.html) has some more detail.